# jquery how to remove a row in dynamic table [SOLVED]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table created dynamically, inside each row there is remove button, I want the row should be removed when I click on remove button, I am using `javascript` and `jquery` `remove()` function, but it's not working.

Here is the table,

```
<table>
<?php $j=0;?>
<?php if(isset($rb)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($rb as $key => $b):?>
        <tr valign="top" id="<?='row_'.$j?>">
           <td><?=++$j?></td>
           <td>
              <textarea name="description" class="item" ><?=$b->item_name?></textarea>
           </td>
           <td><textarea class="unit" name="unit[]"><?=$b->unit?></textarea></td>
           <td><button class="glass_btn"><i class="fa fa-remove" id="<?='rmv_'.$j?>" onclick="removeit('<?='row_'.$j?>');" ></button></td>
            </tr>                        
                <?php endforeach;?>
            <?php endif;?>
</table>
```

and this is `javascript` function :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("button.glass_btn").on("click",function(){
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
})
</script>
```

any helpful answer is appreciated.

Comment: There's no need for passing the id: `$("button.glass_btn").on("click", function() { $(this).closest("tr").remove(); })` (and ids have to be unique: `<i ... id="rmv" ...>`)

Comment: pass "this.id" as parameter in removeit function

Comment: @Akshaypadwal That would be `rmv` and not the id of the row

Comment: @Andreas tnx, it is workign.

Comment: the easiest way :  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
  });